# Memoize the result of satisfying a constraint

Tags: haskell, constraints, memoization

I am searching for a function

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ConstraintKinds #-}

memoC :: (c => a) -> (c => a)
```

such that the resulting `a`s is only evaluated once for the supplied constraint.

#### Another short version

How can I make a value of some type `a` that can only be inspected in the presence of a proof of some constraint `c`?

#### Motivation

I have long sought after a general solution to memoizing values of the form:

```
C a => a
```

Where `C` is some constraint and `a` ranges over all types. With a `Typeable` constraint on `a` and some smart constructors it would be possible to safely memoize the spine of a trie for `Typeable a => b` by building a trie over `TypeRep`s. This question is about the harder part, what to put at the leaves of such a trie.

If we can somehow get `a` into the leaves, the leaves of the trie would need to initially have a value `C a => a` for some concrete type `a`, since dictionaries for classes can't be looked up from the type. Looking up values from the trie would require the dictionary for `C a`. This would seem to amount to modifying the value held at the leaf of the trie based on the passed in dictionary.

If we can't somehow get `a` into the leaves, the leaves would have an even scarier type `C a => b` for a single `b`, and, in providing the dictionary we'd need to prove that the type `a` (and thus the dictionary) can be determined by what is held in `b`, which won't be any more powerful than a `TypeRep`.

#### Evil

It's tempting to reach into the [bag of evil](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/System-IO-Unsafe.html) to build a constructor to hold at the leaves of a trie. Modifying the value held at the leaf of the trie based on the passed in dictionary isn't evil if there's only ever a single dictionary possible for each constraint.

Any "solution" to this could be extremely evil. I am assuming that there's only ever a single dictionary for any constraint. Reflection [`give`s us another evil](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/reflection/docs/Data-Reflection.html#t:Given) that can construct more than one dictionary for a constraint.

Disuade me from this evil.

#### Example

The following should not (and doesn't) memoize the result of providing the constraint `TracedC String`.

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ConstraintKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}

import Debug.Trace (trace)

class TracedC a where
    tracedC :: () -> a  -- The () argument keeps a from being memoized in the dictionary for `TracedC a`

instance TracedC [Char] where
    tracedC _ = trace "tracedC :: String" "Yes"

newtype Memoized c a = Memoized { getMemoized :: c => a }

example :: Memoized (TracedC a) a
example = Memoized (tracedC ())

main = do
    let memo = example :: Memoized (TracedC [Char]) String
    putStrLn $ getMemoized memo
    putStrLn $ getMemoized memo
```

The output is

```
tracedC :: String
Yes
tracedC :: String
Yes
```

A solution would admit a similar example but only evaluate `tracedC () :: TracedC [Char] -> String` once outputting only

```
tracedC :: String
Yes
Yes
```

#### Related attempts

[A map from types to values `f a`](https://gist.github.com/Cedev/83162cdfe4dfff6b0d63) which could be used in [monadic memoization](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/monad-memo) with explicit side effects.

Comment: Well, you could consider storing a `Dynamic`-alike at the leaves of your `TypeRep` trie. But can you actually make a `TypeRep` trie? (Can you even enumerate the `TypeRep`s, which seems like a strictly easier task than creating a trie?)

Comment: I can make a `TypeRep` trie; it's easier than enumerating them. Storing a `Dynamic` at the leaves of it is how you memoize `forall a. Typeable a => f a`

Comment: I'm incredibly curious. Can you share some code?

Comment: The stupid-simple way is to use the `TypeRep`'s `Fingerprint`, which is what the [`Internal`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.4.0.0/docs/Data-Typeable-Internal.html) implementation has used for `Eq` since forever. In base 4.8.0.0 you can can get to it through [`typeRepFingerprint`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Data-Typeable.html#v:typeRepFingerprint). It's as good as `TypeRep`'s `==` which is good enough for me.

Comment: But that's not enough -- it's just step one. You have to somehow go from a `Fingerprint` to a `Typeable` instance to make the `Dynamic` value of the appropriate actual concrete type.

Comment: I got confused about which pieces I've solved which ways, forgot about that problem, and claimed a step too far. I'll edit the Motivation section of the question and link to more code.

Comment: @DanielWagner I've added a section From `TypeRep` to `Typeable` to the end of [my evil answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32577838/414413) with a somewhat evil way to go from the `TypeRep` to a `Typeable a` instance.

Comment: Ah, yup, with manual management of insertions and stuff I can see how it could work.

Comment: Several years on, I find this question very puzzling. What you ask for doesn't seem hard at all with no unsafety: in your example, if you remove `c =>` from the `Memoized` constructor and add `TracedC  a =>` to the signature of `example`, the program compiles and only prints `tracedC :: String` once. This changes the interface to the "memoization constructor" by demanding the class dictionary be available at that time; but your proposal also appears to make this API change. Is this still a problem you face? If so, does my proposal meet your needs, or is there another unstated requirement?

Answer (score 5):

#### Pure Evil

We make a strict constructor around a value that's missing a constraint and an `MVar`.

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ConstraintKinds #-}

import System.IO.Unsafe (unsafePerformIO)
import Control.Concurrent.MVar

data UpToSingle c a = UpToSingle (c => a) !(MVar a)
```

It will only be used by smart constructors and deconstructors. In a module we wouldn't export the `UpToSingle` constructor.

We provide a smart constructor for it; constructing the constructor is equivalent to allocating the `MVar`.

```
upToSingle :: (c => a) -> UpToSingle c a
upToSingle a = UpToSingle a $ unsafePerformIO newEmptyMVar
```

We also provide a smart deconstructor. It uses whatever value's there or computes one with the provided dictionary. It relies on there being a single possible dictionary for `c`.

```
fillMVar :: MVar a -> a -> IO a
fillMVar mvar a = do
    tryPutMVar mvar a
    readMVar mvar

withSingle :: c => UpToSingle c a -> a
withSingle (UpToSingle a mvar) = unsafePerformIO $ fillMVar mvar a
```

#### Evil Exemplified

Using the same example traced code as in the question.

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}

import Debug.Trace (trace)

class TracedC a where
    tracedC :: () -> a  -- The () argument keeps a from being memoized in the dictionary for `TracedC a`

instance TracedC [Char] where
    tracedC _ = trace "tracedC :: String" "Yes"
```

And `UpToSingle` in place of `Memoized`, `upToSingle` in place of the `Memoized` constructor, and `withSingle` in place of `getMemoized`

```
example :: UpToSingle (TracedC a) a
example = upToSingle (tracedC ())

main = do
    let memo = example :: UpToSingle (TracedC [Char]) String
    putStrLn $ withSingle memo
    putStrLn $ withSingle memo
```

We get the desired output

```
tracedC :: String
Yes
Yes
```

#### Doubly Evil

Combined with [reflection](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/reflection) the evil of either `UpToSingle` or `Given` is revealed. Both of the last two lines should print the same thing. By substitution they are both `give 9 (withSingle (upToSingle given))`.

```
main = do
    let g1 = upToSingle given :: UpToSingle (Given Integer) Integer
    let g2 = upToSingle given :: UpToSingle (Given Integer) Integer
    print $ give 7 (withSingle g1)
    print $ give 9 (withSingle g2)
    print $ give 9 (withSingle g1)
```

They actually print the following:

```
7
9
7
```

The `give 7` evaluated before the `give 9` passed a different `Given Integer` dictionary to `g1` than the `give 9` would and had the side effect of changing the result of `give 9 (withSingle (upToSingle given))`. Either `UpToSingle` is evil for assuming dictionaries are unique or `give` is evil for constructing new non-unique dictionaries.

#### From TypeRep to Typeable

We can use the same trick of delaying when a constraint is discovered to build the leaves of a memo trie for `Typeable a => f a`. Conceptually the leaves of the trie are each one of the following `GDynamic`s.

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

import Data.Typeable
import Control.Monad (liftM)

data GDynamic f where
    GDynamic :: Typeable a => f a -> GDynamic f

unGDynamic :: Typeable a => GDynamic f -> Maybe (f a)
unGDynamic (GDynamic f) = gcast f
```

When constructing the trie, we don't have the `Typeable a` instances needed to construct the `GDynamic`s. We only have a `TypeRep`. Instead we will steal the `Typeable a` instance provided when the value is accessed. A `GDynamic` value up to a `Typeable a` instance is the `TypeRep`, the definition of the value `forall a.` and an `MVar` to hold the actual `GDynamic`.

```
data UpToTypeable f = UpToTypeable TypeRep (forall a. Typeable a => f a) !(MVar (GDynamic f))
```

We don't export the `UpToTypeable` constructor, instead exporting only a smart constructor and deconstructor. When `UpToTypeable` is constructed we allocate the `MVar`.

```
upToTypeable :: TypeRep -> (forall a. Typeable a => f a) -> UpToTypeable f
upToTypeable r f = UpToTypeable r f $ unsafePerformIO newEmptyMVar
```

When it is deconstructed the user provides a `Typeable a` instance. If it has the same `TypeRep` as that stored in the `UpToTypeable` we accept that as proof that the types are equal and use the provided `Typeable a` instance to fill in the value of the `GDynamic`.

```
withTypeable :: forall f a. Typeable a => UpToTypeable f -> Maybe (f a)
withTypeable (UpToTypeable r f mvar) = unsafePerformIO $ do
    if typeRep (Proxy :: Proxy a) == r
    then liftM unGDynamic $ fillMVar mvar (GDynamic (f :: f a))
    else return Nothing
```

This should be safe since future GHC versions will forbid user provided instances for `Typeable`.

Comment: "Either `UpToSingle` is evil for assuming dictionaries are unique or `give` is evil for constructing new non-unique dictionaries." Why not both?

Comment: `give` is the evil one. Incoherent instances break brains. I'm curious why you use something as heavy as an `MVar`.

Comment: In this case, I think you should be able to use an `IORef (Maybe a)` instead of an `MVar a`, and avoid synchronization costs. The worst that could happen, I believe, is that the value could be calculated by two different threads. If that's a concern, you might use a `TMVar a` (just a wrapper around `TVar (Maybe a)`) which gets you thread safety without here-unnecessary fairness guarantees.

Comment: @dfeuer I don't know either. I must have had `MVar`s on my mind from something; I'd use an `IORef` if I were doing it right now. It's likely that I was worried about unique initialization, since I was worried about it just now re-reading my answer.

Comment: For extra evil, use a Kmettian trick: create a single, heavily `NOINLINE`d top-level value to serve as a "null pointer", and then use `reallyUnsafePtrEquality# a nullObj` to check for null. This lets you just use `IORef a`, initialized to `nullObj`.

Comment: For the record, I don't actually think there's anything evil about what you're doing here. I wonder if special compiler support could make this really efficient. In the mean time, here's my attempt at a bit of an improvement. I do not guarantee that this will always work; ekmett could probably give some tips on that. http://lpaste.net/2030192553617260544